# Calculate $\log_{\frac{1}{2}}{(2\sqrt[3]{4})}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have this exercise:$$\log_{\frac{1}{2}}{(2\sqrt[3]{4})}$$

There is not equation or something else, how should I solve this type of exercise?

Comment: Which one should we calculate?

Comment: sorry, edited the title

Comment: $\displaystyle\log_{(1/2)}(2\sqrt[3]4)=\frac {\log_{2}(2\sqrt[3]4)}{\log_2(1/2)}=\frac{\log_{2}(2^14^{1/3})}{\log_2(2^{-1})}=\frac{\log_{2}(2^12^{2/3})}{-1}=-\log_{2}(2^{5/3})=-\frac53$

Comment: A sometimes useful identity worth remembering is $\log_{b^n}(x) = \frac{\log_{b}(x)}{n}$ valid for all integral $n$.

Comment: @KennyLau I think you could have posted that as an answer rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$2 = \frac{1}{2}^{-1}$

$\sqrt[3]{4} = 2 ^{2/3}= (1/2)^{-2/3}$

$\log_{\frac{1}{2}}{(2\sqrt[3]{4})} = -1 - 2/3 = -5/3$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\log_{1/2}(2\sqrt[3]4) & =\log_{1/2}(2)+\frac{1}3\log_{1/2}(4) \\
& =-1-\frac{2}3
\end{align*}